# Angular - how to open link in same component with routerLink

Tags: javascript, angular, router, routerlink

i'm facing a problem in my web application with `routerLink`. I created a card (`div`) and I d'like to click on it and open another component on the same page.

Here is my code:

```
    <a class="app-card" [routerLink]="['/', '#app=5h3kemncnri4i3nf']">
      <div class="app-card__header">
        <h2>{{'HOME.APPLICATION.APP_ONE'|translate}}</h2>
      </div>
    </a>
```

This part `#app=5h3kemncnri4i3nf` is an `ID` which opens the app on the same page. But wit the code above it didn't work - nothing happen when I click on it .

If I hover the `<a>` in the browser, I get the following output:

`localhost:4200/%23app%5h3kemncnri4i3nf`

I'm expecting to open the link:

`http://localhost:4200/home#app=5h3kemncnri4i3nf` on the same page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you replacing current component or adding below /above new component ?

Comment: above the current component - as a modul